# Javascript parsing for urls not working in chrome and IE when port number exceeds max value

Tags: javascript

I am having url in text box in which I need to convert this into url and check if the port number is greater than 65535.

I using the following code:

```
function parseURL(url) {
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
return {
    source: url,
    protocol: a.protocol.replace(':', ''),
    host: a.hostname,
    port: a.port,
    query: a.search

};
```

This method working fine upto 65535 port number in all browser. When I am giving 65536 it shows the follwing output in chrome :

i.port = "0";
i.host = "";

And for the same input it shows "invalid arguement" in Internet explorer. 
This is working only in firefox.

Any other method to achieve this ??

Comment: is this for specific port number ??

Comment: No port number greater than 65535.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum possible port number is **65535** i.e., 2^16 - 1.

Hence anything above will fail.

Ports 0-1023 - well-known ports

Ports 1024-49151 - registered ports: vendors use for applications

Ports >49151 - dynamic / private ports

Comment: Ideally it should not be working as per the current standards,
https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-port 
mozilla only refers to this documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Constructor